# Unable to send transaction(s) to tor

Tags: monerod, tor

I have set up a Public Node following these instructions https://monerodocs.org/running-node/open-node-tor-onion/ and at the end ran the tests and got a response each time. However, I keep getting the following warnings:

```
[P2P9]  WARNING net.p2p.tx      src/cryptonote_protocol/levin_notify.cpp:681    Unable to send transaction(s) to tor - no suitable outbound connections at height ........
[P2P9]  WARNING net.p2p.tx      src/cryptonote_protocol/levin_notify.cpp:681    Unable to send transaction(s) to tor - no suitable outbound connections at height ........
[P2P7]  WARNING net.p2p.tx      src/cryptonote_protocol/levin_notify.cpp:681    Unable to send transaction(s) to tor - no suitable outbound connections at height ........
[P2P7]  WARNING net.p2p.tx      src/cryptonote_protocol/levin_notify.cpp:681    Unable to send transaction(s) to tor - no suitable outbound connections at height ........
[P2P1]  WARNING net.p2p.tx      src/cryptonote_protocol/levin_notify.cpp:681    Unable to send transaction(s) to tor - no suitable outbound connections at height ........
[P2P2]  WARNING net.p2p.tx      src/cryptonote_protocol/levin_notify.cpp:681    Unable to send transaction(s) to tor - no suitable outbound connections at height ........
```

What else can be the problem here? via the tor network my node looks OK.

Comment: Are you connected to the other tor nodes? Is your daemon fully synchronized? Are the tor nodes you are trying to connect to synchronized and up to date? Are you running the latest Monero release?

Comment: My node is fully synchronized & running the latest version. http://5akilsd4pgxsie7vigrxm37md6jc3xgjiimzgfbt7tjxazbxy37hrlyd.onion:18081/get_info
How can I see if I am connected to other tor nodes or if the other nodes are synchronized?

Comment: \*_connections_count zero, \*_peerlist_size zero.

Comment: Ok, but the rpc is running in restricted mode, that's why this information is not displayed, right?

Comment: Yes, running restricted would cause those to show 0.

Comment: So, is there another way to get this information?

Comment: don't start your node restricted or run sync_into in monerod.

Comment: sync_into does not work. I must run in restricted mode, because its a public node, usable for everyone.

Comment: sync_info is an interactive daemon command.

Comment: Note that MoneroDocs.org is sadly no longer available. A mirror for this same page which will get future community updates is https://getmonero.dev/docs/running-node/open-node-tor-onion.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Monerodocs author here. I actually had the very same issue you described.

These two things combined should help:

- For each `add-peer` config entry add similar `add-priority-node` entry. This is a workaround to force `monerod` to reconnect with these peers after they drop (which is very common on Tor).
- Pick onion nodes that are actually online and working from these fine rankings: https://xmrguide.org/remote_nodes and https://monero.fail/ instead of static documentation example.

Obviously, one could also remove the `tx-proxy=tor,127.0.0.1:9050,16` option to broadcast wallet-originating transactions over clearnet. But that is what we wanted to avoid with this setup in the first place. For non-anonymous open nodes it's probably better to not be considered the "originating" node.

PS I've updated the docs to reflect this.